# A Link for Facebook Likes (no button)

Tags: facebook

I have a quiet and minimal site that I'd like to add a "share on Facebook" link to. My preference would be for a simple text link. Is this possible anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have very good documentation on this topic.

http://www.facebook.com/share/:

> Regardless of the implementation,
>   Share always uses the url format below
>   to show the user the preview. Feel
>   free to create your own implementation
>   based on this.
>
> http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&t= We also
>   provide an API to query data on shared
>   items.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F" target="_top">Share on Facebook</a>
```

You may also consider using `window.open()` to provide a appropriately sized window.